# jqGrid Error in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid, it is currently working fine in FF, IE8, Chrome, Safari. But in IE7 I get this error:

> **'this.rows.0.cells' is null or not an object**
>
> jquery.jqGrid.min.js
>
> Code:
> 0
>
> Line: 122 Char: 278

Has anyone come accross this before? Is there a known fix?

### update

Here is my PHP code:

```
$qry = 'SELECT stock_num, shape, carat, clarity, color, cut 
        FROM rapnet_diamonds 
        WHERE (carat BETWEEN "0" AND "5") 
        AND (color BETWEEN "D" AND "Z") 
        AND ( CASE clarity 
            WHEN "FL" THEN 0 
            WHEN "IF" THEN 1 
            WHEN "VVS1" THEN 2 
            WHEN "VVS2" THEN 3 
            WHEN "VS1" THEN 4 
            WHEN "VS2" THEN 5 
            WHEN "SI1" THEN 6 
            WHEN "SI2" THEN 7 
            WHEN "I1" THEN 8 
            WHEN "I2" THEN 9 
            WHEN "I3" THEN 10 
            ELSE -1 END BETWEEN "0" AND "10") 
        AND ( CASE cut 
            WHEN "ideal" THEN 0 
            WHEN "excellent" THEN 1 
            WHEN "very good" THEN 2
            WHEN "good" THEN 3 
            WHEN "fair" THEN 4 
            WHEN "poor" THEN 5 
            ELSE -1 END BETWEEN "0" AND "5")';

$grid->SelectCommand = $qry;
// set the ouput format to json
$grid->dataType = 'json';
// Let the grid create the model
$grid->setColModel();


// Set grid caption using the option caption
$grid->setGridOptions(array(
    "caption"=>"Diamonds Found",
    "rowNum"=>200,
    "sortname"=>"diamond_id",
    "hoverrows"=>true,
    "sortable"=>0,
    "scroll"=>1,
    "height"=>300,
    "altRows"=>true,
    "colNames"=> array('ID', 'Shape', 'Carat', 'Clarity', 'Color', 'Cut')
    ));
// Change some property of the field(s)
$grid->setColProperty("diamond_id", array("label"=>"ID", "width"=>60));
// Enjoy
$grid->renderGrid('#grid','#pager',true, null, null, true,true);
$conn = null;
```

Here is what gets generated:

```
<table id='grid'></table>
    <div id='pager'></div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {jQuery('#grid').jqGrid({"width":"650","hoverrows":true,"viewrecords":true,"jsonReader":{"repeatitems":false,"subgrid":{"repeatitems":false}},"xmlReader":{"repeatitems":false,"subgrid":{"repeatitems":false}},"gridview":true,"url":"myfirstgrid.php?yellow=","editurl":"myfirstgrid.php?yellow=","cellurl":"myfirstgrid.php?yellow=","onSelectRow":function(rowid, selected) 
    { 
        if(rowid != null) { 
           // alert("selected: "+rowid);
           loadSelectedDiamond(rowid);
        } 
    } ,"gridComplete":function() 
    { 
        diamondsReloaded();
    } ,"caption":"Diamonds Found","rowNum":200,"sortname":"diamond_id","sortable":0,"scroll":1,"height":300,"altRows":true,"colNames":["ID","Shape","Carat","Clarity","Color","Cut"],"datatype":"json","colModel":[{"name":"stock_num","index":"stock_num","editable":true,"sorttype":"string","key":true},{"name":"shape","index":"shape","editable":true,"sorttype":"string"},{"name":"carat","index":"carat","editable":true,"sorttype":"numeric"},{"name":"clarity","index":"clarity","editable":true,"sorttype":"string"},{"name":"color","index":"color","editable":true,"sorttype":"string"},{"name":"cut","index":"cut","editable":true,"sorttype":"string"}],"postData":{"oper":"grid"},"prmNames":{"page":"page","rows":"rows","sort":"sidx","order":"sord","search":"_search","nd":"nd","id":false,"filter":"filters","searchField":"searchField","searchOper":"searchOper","searchString":"searchString","oper":"oper","query":"grid","addoper":"add","editoper":"edit","deloper":"del","excel":"excel","subgrid":"subgrid","totalrows":"totalrows"},"pager":"#pager"}); });
    </script>
```

I am using jqgrid version 3.8

Comment: Try using the development code, and actually look at what line number the problem is occurring on. Also, what are you trying to do with the library that causes this problem?

Comment: It can be different reasons how you can receive such kind of error. Which version of jqGrid you use? Could you post a code example which reproduce your problem? In Fiddler tool of in Firebug you can save the data which the server send back to the jqGrid. This test data could be also helpful.

Comment: It seems much more like a commercial version of the jqGrid from the http://www.trirand.net/. Do you tried to get official support? Moreover I wrote you before that the problem can be the data which will be send from the server. PHP code give no data. If you post the data, one could save there saved in the text file to a server and test the code without having any server components. JavaScript functions `diamondsReloaded()` and `loadSelectedDiamond()` you not included currently.

Comment: @Oleg, the diamondsReloaded inserts in another location how many results are found, and loadSelectedDiamond inserts in another location more data about the row they click on. They don't really interact with the grid aside from calling: `jQuery("#grid").getGridParam("records")`. It is a commercial version, but currently only a demo I am evaluating, I sent them an email asking for support. Thanks.

Comment: @Oleg by the way the page is located here: http://www.kranichs.com/diamond_search/ if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you post the link with your test solution I could examine a little the problem myself. I could see that the main page load data from the URL http://www.kranichs.com/diamond_search/myfirstgrid.php. The full get request looks like http://www.kranichs.com/diamond_search/myfirstgrid.php?yellow=&oper=grid&_search=false&nd=1283196859096&rows=200&page=1&sidx=diamond_id&sord=asc. I could also see with respect of [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) that the data which will be send back from the server **are not correct JSON data**. It seems to me that it is your main problem. The data looks like following

```
4cb2
{"records":"136635","page":1,"total":684,"rows":[{...}]}
0
```

The part `{"records":"136635","page":1,"total":684,"rows":[{...}]}` are correct JSON data which jqGrid need. I tested with http://www.trirand.net/demophp.aspx and can see the same problem, but another page http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnetmvc.aspx which are more close to me **has not the problem**!

I recommend you to test demo pages http://www.trirand.net/demophp.aspx and http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnetmvc.aspx on the same computer where you have IE7 problem which you described.

I am only a user of jqGrid and not a developer of jqGrid, so if you found a some problem in jqGrid PHP version post it to http://www.trirand.net/. I personally bought some time ago ASP.NET MVC Subscription with the full source code to support Developers of jqGrid (but use till now only free version of jqGrid) so I have only access to ASP.NET MVC code and not to PHP version. So if your problem exist in the PHP version you have to post to the forum on http://www.trirand.net/.

Comment: Ah ha! After contacting them, it was a known issue that they fixed. They said all I need to do is download the newer version. Thanks for your help!